# VSCode - Not able to resue Env variables set inside terminal.integrated.env.windows

Tags: environment-variables, visual-studio-code

In the user settings.json, I used the option to set a couple of Env variables & paths that I would only require inside VSCode :

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
      "ANDROID_HOME":"D:\\Android",
      "GIT_FOR_PATH":"D:\\Git\\cmd",
      "PATH":"${env:PATH};${env:ANDROID_HOME};${env:GIT_FOR_PATH}"
    }
```

But, when I echo %PATH% post restarting VSCode, I just get ->
`Original-Path-Value;${env:ANDROID_HOME};${env:GIT_FOR_PATH}`

Windows 10 - VSCode 1.47.2

I have tried with a few alternatives also ->
%ANDROIND_HOME%
${ANDROID_HOME}

Is this feature of substituing Env variables in other Env variables supported with a different syntax/be added in any future version/ popular workaround?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be supported. Why not just type it in? Unless you explicitly call them? Why isn't git already a global env varibale for your computer in general? Not that it's any of my business. Just curious

Comment: @soulshined thanks for the clarification, I am currently typing it in directly & using it. Umm, I use Git, Android variables only inside VSCode & it's integrated terminal. So, thought I would bundle it into settings.json instead of user/system-variables

Comment: Ah. In that case, if you use Powershell integrated terminal, vscode uses its own Powershell profile. You could just add it to that. Not sure if it is the same for bash but not at a computer to check

Comment: @soulshined I usually use cmd as my primary integrated terminal with the bash shell for Git commands alone. So, mostly not looking at Powershell as an option currently but like you said, PS-profile changes might not reflect in Bash shell

Answer (score 0):

In your user settings (File > Preferences > Settings), add the following:

"terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration": true